# Access another table over attribute

Tags: laravel

I have defined attribute in model which gets data from another table, but I haven't defined a relation between those two tables:

LeaseRequest model

```
public function getSecurityDepositEntryAttribute() {
    return Rent::where([
        ['property_id', $this->property_id],
        ['lease_request_id', $this->id],
        ['type', 'security_deposit_migration'],
    ])->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->first();
}
```

Can I now filter `LeaseRequest` table using this attribute? I have tried this, but getting `BadMethodCallException`:

```
LeaseRequest::whereHas('security_deposit_entry', function($query) {
    $query->whereColumnNotIn('status', ['refund_in_process', 'refunded']);
})->get();
```

If this is not possible, can I define relationship between those two tables with predefined `where` clauses like in attribute?

Comment: You are going to have to set the foreign keys on the tables so you have to change your migration and then setup the lationship in the models

Comment: Is there really a reason to have property_id in the query when you are already matching against the primary key (`$this->id`)?  If not, then this is a simple relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No not possible you have to use relations and to use [compoships lib](https://github.com/topclaudy/compoships):

```
public function rent() {
    return $this->hasOne(Rent::class,['lease_request_id','property_id'],['id','property_id'])
   ->where('type', 'security_deposit_migration')
   ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc');
}
```

['lease_request_id','property_id'] are the foriegn keys

['id','property_id'] are the local keys

then you can use whereHas

Comment: As far as I see it,  id is the primary key of this table (unless poorly named) so there's no need to try to match against a composite key in the relationship.

Comment: Well, it's a 'has' relationships not 'belongs to' so it might be hasMany if it relied on one field or maybe he just wants the first record with other conditions to be met.

Comment: There's no possibility of that because id is a primary key, you can't have two rows with the same id with different property_id's.  In my opinion, the OP is forcing a composite key where there shouldn't be a need for one.

Comment: You are correct if the relation was belongsTo but this is a hasOne/Many as LeaseRequest has Many/One Rent